# How to handle low temperatures using Arduino Uno?

Tags: arduino-uno, temperature-sensor, safety

I want to create a simple electronic temperature sensor using the Arduino Uno.

The environments I want it to handle is inside a fridge and near a heater.

Although I am sure the Arduino can easily handle a heater; my issue is that the Arduino may not be able to handle a fridge.

A fridge also has the added problem of causing water vapor (and we all know water + electronics is never a good idea).

So my question is:

- How would I create a temperature sensor using my Arduino Uno, that I can put in my fridge?
- Are there any other problems I have not considered and how do I solve them?
- Will I need a special type of casing? If so, which type?
- Is an Arduino Uno even the best tool for this task?

Comment: Condensation is mostly a problem when you take the cold Arduino out of the fridge, into the warm room. Putting the entire project into a ziplock bag is probably sufficient protection.

Answer (score 1):

Your Arduino does not have to be in the fridge, just the sensor. You can always choose waterproof sensor [like this one](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11050) to use with the arduino. Then you can always store your arduino outside the fridge. Same goes for the heater. Try to keep the arduino at room temperatures to avoid decreasing its life unnecessarily.

As for an actual answer to the temperature ranges, [here is a good answer](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/633/how-cold-or-hot-can-my-arduino-uno-get)

Comment: That makes sense, but I kinda want the entire object in the fridge for my specific use case. The reason being is that I'm making a game, where the player is tasked to put this cube (i.e. a packaged arduino) in different temperatures (although the player of course doesn't know that). If the correct temperature is found it does something (like open a door via wifi).

Comment: in that case you just need an airtight box (look up one on google). Any box will do, like the food boxes. You can also drill holes for probes and seal them with silicon. [here is a commercial box](https://learn.adafruit.com/lady-adas-bento-box)

Comment: My other issue is ensuring enough ventilation. Wouldn't a airtight box cause humidity?

Comment: Regarding moisture you could use a moisture absorbing package (e.g. filled with salt or some silicate).

Comment: like @LStrike said, use a moisture absorbing package to absorb the moisture already in the box. Since it is airtight moisture from the fridge will not get in. The component on the board in your case do not need any special cooling, especially in such a cold environment.

Answer (score 1):

Humidity would be your biggest enemy. The fridge is a very moist environment for two reasons:

- The colder the air temperature, the less moisture it can hold overall, thus saturating more quickly and reaching a higher relative humidity.
- Lots of moist foodstuffs in an enclosed space.

You should be OK as long as the enclosure you choose has plenty of ventilation to avoid a temperature differential or trapping moisture.  Either of those two conditions could cause and even larger increase in humidity or, worse, condensate to form.

Comment: But how can I ensure I have a container that is both waterproof and enough ventilation

Comment: You don't need a waterproof case unless you plan on submerging the Uno in water as well.